# How can I clear a variable in assembler?

Tags: x86, assembly

I'm using a BYTE variable in assembler to hold partial statements before they're copied to a permanent location. I'm trying to figure out how I could clear that after each new entry. I tried moving an empty variable into it, but that only replaced the first character space of the variable. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use XOR instead of MOV.  It's faster.

```
XOR r1, r1
```

Comment: I tried xor, but it fails to build with variables. However, I use it regularly with registers.

Comment: @xboxmods `AND byte [var],0h`?

Comment: @xboxmods because you can't have memory in both instruction arguments. You must either move from an immediate or a register to memory

Comment: What takes time is the loading of the constant `0`. So the only fastest way to do this AFAIK is by using `XOR r1, r1`.

Comment: That's true for registers, yes.  [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617).  For one byte in memory, `AND` is useless: `mov byte [var], 0` is the same size.  For wider memory operands, AND can still be `imm8`, while unfortunately `mov dword [var], 0` can only be encoded with an imm32, 4 bytes of zeros.  So AND is smaller but slower.

Answer (score 1):

For a variable (assuming your var is stored in the memory):

```
mov var1, 0
```

For an array (as far as I got, that's what you are talking about?):

```
xor al, al
lea edi, var1
mov ecx, <var1_array_size>
cld
rep stosb
```

Comment: `xor eax,eax` is [a more efficient way to zero AL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and), and `mov edi, OFFSET var1` is more efficient than LEA (unless this is 64-bit code where that's a RIP-relative LEA in MASM syntax).

Comment: `rep stosb` with a byte count vs. `rep stosd` with a dword count depends on the CPU: a few CPUs with the ERMSB feature have a `rep stosb` that's actually faster, but modern CPUs handle `rep stosd` just as efficiently as `rep stosb`.  While older CPUs handle it more efficiently, at least for non-tiny memsets.  [Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43343231)